# DVC Error comes when Fast API executing through IIS

Tags: iis, fastapi, dvc

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\appdirs.py", line 481, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
    dir = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, getattr(shellcon, csidl_name), 0, 0)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)
```

StdOut:

StdErr:

Trying to run the application through IIS
It is working fine in FastAPI virtual env

Comment: Change application pool identity to a suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you encounter indicates that while running the application through IIS, access is denied when you try to access a folder or resource in the application.

In IIS, each application pool runs with a specific identity. You need to ensure that the user identity that runs IIS has the necessary permissions to access the resources required by the application. You can change this identity in IIS by right-clicking the application pool, selecting Advanced Settings, and modifying the Identity property.

If you choose not to modify the application pool "identity", check the permissions on the folders and files that the application is trying to access. You may need to grant read and execute permissions on these folders to the identity of the application pool you are currently using.